# How to apply patch from tortoise to cornerstone

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, patch, cornerstone

Is it possible to apply patch from tortoise to cornerstone.
I tried several times but cornerstone tells for all files FAILED and created only *.orig files??

for FAILED filed it shows only : (Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work ensure you are:

1. Creating and applying the patch from/to the same revision of the file.
   I.e. the contents of file to which patch is applied should be equal to the contents of the file from which patch was created (one revision before the patch revision).
2. The directory from which patch was created should be equal to the current directory when patch is applied.

   I.e. if you are creating patch for the file `/first/second/x.txt` while your current directory is `/first/`, then it should be applied from the directory `/first/`. It will not work in `/first/second/` (unless you will provide special options to the patch utility).